# LaTeX citation overwrites year field with date

Tags: biblatex, jabref

I am using JabRef to create my bibliography and it includes a date field, as well as a time stamp in every entry.
When citing in-line, I get the following warnings:

> ```
> Overwriting field 'year' with year value from field 'date' for entry 'keyname'
> Overwriting field 'month' with month value from field 'date' for entry 'keyname'
> ```

and instead of the year of publication (i.e. 1988) the citation command shows 2017 (hence the year of date).
I have tried to delete the date field from JabRef, but was not able to do so. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{BUNKER.bib}


\begin{document}
    \section{Multivariate GARCH Models}
        \subsection{Introduction}
            ...estimates is given by \textcite{Alizadeh2004} and \cite{Bollerslev1988}

\end{document}
```

This is my bib file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{Bollerslev1988,
  author    = {Tim Bollerslev and Robert F. Engle and Jeffrey M. Wooldridge},
  title     = {A Capital Asset Pricing Model with Time-Varying Covariances},
  journal   = {Journal of Political Economy},
  year      = {1988},
  date      = {2017-06-15},
  volume    = {96},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {116--131},
  doi       = {10.1086/261527},
  urldate   = {2017-06-15},
  month     = {feb},
  publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
}

@Article{Alizadeh2004,
  author    = {Amir H. Alizadeh and Manolis G. Kavussanos and David A. Menachof},
  title     = {Hedging against bunker price fluctuations using petroleum futures contracts: constant versus time-varying hedge ratios},
  journal   = {Applied Economics},
  year      = {2004},
  date      = {2017-06-15},
  volume    = {36},
  number    = {12},
  pages     = {1337--1353},
  doi       = {10.1080/0003684042000176801},
  month     = {jul},
  publisher = {Informa {UK} Limited},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}
```

[image: Screenshot of general preferences]

[image: Screenshot entry]

Comment: You (or jabref) shouldn't use the date field for a timestamp.

Comment: I'm using jabref's ID-based entry generator (DOI), so it automatically used the date field for the timestamp. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: You could use JabRef's `biblatex` mode. `date` should be the date of publication of the entry.

Comment: I don't know, I have only an rather old jabref version installed. But I haven't seen any question about this until now so I don't think that it is the normal behaviour.

Comment: I am already using biblatex mode. I have the latest JabRef version (including the latest build of the master branch, since the DOI import hadn't been working properly)

Comment: I am for now using set/clear/rename fields under the Quality tab to set all date field values to empty, which is working, but I would still be happy about any solution which solves my issue in a more elegant way.

Comment: How do you add an entry? Can you show a screenshot? I'm not a regular JabRef user, but to me it does not look as though JabRef would randomly add the current date in `date`.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the 'general' tab of your JabRef preferences?

Comment: Can you also show a screenshot of an entry? What field is indicated as 'field name' in 'Mark new entries with addition date'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the development versions of JabRef. All new entries automatically have their `date` field set to the current date.

Even when you use the 'ID-based entry generator' to generate a `.bib` entry, the `date` field is automatically populated with the current date.

I have reported this as a bug https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2915